# How can I subtract 3 days from a date?

Tags: php, date

I have a sync script that syncs domain expiration dates with next due date for billing. Right now the script works great if you want the expiration date to equal the next due date.

But I need the next due date to be three days before the expiration, so I need the code to subtract 3 days from the `$expirydate` in the following code snippet (Full script code is below):

```
if ($SyncNextDueDate) {
update_query ( "tbldomains", array ("nextduedate" => $expirydate ), array ("domain" => $domainname ) );
}
```

Full code:

```
<?php

require dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/../../../dbconnect.php';
require ROOTDIR . '/includes/functions.php';
require ROOTDIR . '/includes/registrarfunctions.php';

$cronreport = 'Internet.bs Domain Sync Report<br>
---------------------------------------------------<br>
';
/**
* gets expiration date from domain list command
* @param string $data - command TEXT response
* @return array - associative array having as key the domain name and as value the expiration date
*/
function parseResult($data) {
$result = array ();
$data=strtolower($data);
$arr = explode ( "\n", $data );
$totalDomains = 0;
$assocArr = array ();
foreach ( $arr as $str ) {
    list ( $varName, $value ) = explode ( "=", $str );
    $varName = trim ( $varName );
    $value = trim ( $value );
    if ($varName == "domaincount") {
        $totalDomains = intval ( $value );
    }
    $assocArr [$varName] = $value;

}
if ($assocArr ["status"] != "success") { 
    return false;   
}

for($i = 0; $i < $totalDomains; $i ++) {
    list ( $y, $m, $d ) = explode ( "/", $assocArr ["domain_" . $i . "_expiration"] );
    $status = strtolower ( $assocArr ["domain_" . $i . "_status"] );
            if(!is_numeric($y) || !is_numeric($m) || !is_numeric($d)){
                $ddat = array ("expiry" => null, "status" => $status );
            } else {
                $ddat = array ("expiry" => mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y ), "status" => $status );
            }
    $result [strtolower ( $assocArr ["domain_" . $i . "_name"] )] = $ddat;
    if (isset ( $assocArr ["domain_" . $i . "_punycode"] )) {
        $result [strtolower ( $assocArr ["domain_" . $i . "_punycode"] )] = $ddat;
    }
}
return $result;
}

$params = getregistrarconfigoptions ( 'internetbs' );

$postfields = array ();
$postfields ['ApiKey'] = $params ['Username'];
$postfields ['Password'] = $params ['Password'];
$postfields ['ResponseFormat'] = 'TEXT';
$postfields ['CompactList'] = 'no';
$testMode = trim(strtolower($params ['TestMode']))==="on";
$SyncNextDueDate = trim(strtolower($params ["SyncNextDueDate"]))==="on";

if ($testMode) {
$url = 'https://testapi.internet.bs/domain/list';
} else {
$url = 'https://api.internet.bs/domain/list';
}

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );

curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "WHMCS Internet.bs Corp. Expiry Sync Robot" );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );

$data = curl_exec ( $ch );
$curl_err = false;


  if (curl_error ( $ch )) {
    $curl_err = 'CURL Error: ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ' - ' . curl_error ( $ch );
    exit ( 'CURL Error: ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ' - ' . curl_error ( $ch ) );
    }
    curl_close ( $ch );
    if ($curl_err) {
        $cronreport .= "Error connecting to API: $curl_err";
    } else {

    $result = parseResult ( $data );
    if (! $result) {
        $cronreport .= "Error connecting to API:<br>" . nl2br ( $data ) . "<br>";
    } else {
        $queryresult = select_query ( "tbldomains", "domain", "registrar='internetbs' AND (status='Pending Transfer' OR status='Active')" );
        while ( $data = mysql_fetch_array ( $queryresult ) ) {
            $domainname = trim ( strtolower ( $data ['domain'] ) );
            if (isset ( $result [$domainname] )) {
                                if(!is_null($result [$domainname] ["expiry"])){
                                    $expirydate = date ( "Y-m-d", $result [$domainname] ["expiry"] );
                                } else {
                                    $expirydate = false;
                                }
                $status = $result [$domainname] ["status"];
                if ($status == 'ok') {
                    update_query ( "tbldomains", array ("status" => "Active" ), array ("domain" => $domainname ) );
                }
                if ($expirydate) {
                    update_query ( "tbldomains", array ("expirydate" => $expirydate ), array ("domain" => $domainname ) );
                    if ($SyncNextDueDate) {
                        update_query ( "tbldomains", array ("nextduedate" => $expirydate ), array ("domain" => $domainname ) );
                    }
                    $cronreport .= '' . 'Updated ' . $domainname . ' expiry to ' . frommysqldate ( $expirydate ) . '<br>';
                }
            } else {
                $cronreport .= '' . 'ERROR: ' . $domainname . ' -  Domain does not appear in the account at Internet.bs.<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
logactivity ( 'Internet.bs Domain Sync Run' );
sendadminnotification ( 'system', 'WHMCS Internet.bs Domain Syncronisation Report', $cronreport );

?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$expirydate`?

Comment: It depends on the expiration date of the domain. The script logs into the domain registrar and then syncs all the domain expiration dates there with the ones in my WHMCS for billing.                   $expirydate = date ( "Y-m-d", $result [$domainname] ["expiry"] );

Comment: I just needed to see the format. See my answer below for how to add three days to this date

Comment: LOL. I think I'm in a little over my head on this one. I have no idea where I would add this code to the script. I will add the entire script to my question.

Comment: Just put it right before your code.

Comment: Everything works in the script fine, just need "nextduedate" => $expirydate - 3 days. :)

Comment: That's what my code does

Comment: right before the code block you posted here

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime($expirydate);
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P3D');
$expirydate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

or as a one-liner:

```
$expirydate = (new DateTime($expirydate))->sub(new DateInterval('P3D'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Here's a slightly different method:

```
$date = new DateTime($expirydate);
$date->modify('-3 days');
$expirydate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your time.